# The Object you want to instantiate is null

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to instantiate a prefab from resources folder using the name from a text file located in my resources folder. Prefab is also located in my resources folder. However, I get an error saying "the object I want to instantiate is null".

When I directly give the name of prefab it works. I cannot seem to understand the issue.

My code is :

```
public void Loadd() 
{
    TextAsset txtasset = (TextAsset)Resources.Load (txtfile);
    txtcontents = txtasset.text;
    string[] linesinfile = txtasset.text.Split ('\n');
    for(int i= 0; i<1; i++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < buttonholder.Length; x++)
        {
            //GameObject Instance = Instantiate (Resources.Load ("F260001", typeof(GameObject))) as GameObject;   // works
            string name = linesinfile [x];
            Debug.Log (name);
            GameObject Instance = Instantiate (Resources.Load (name, typeof(GameObject))) as GameObject;
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: what does it print at debug.log? check its length too (maybe not trimmed)

Comment: an example of the txt file it would help! Also the log ;) !

Comment: Here is a link for Debug.log.. http://i.imgur.com/ghJs0Xw.png

Comment: Here is a link which shows my text file..  http://i.imgur.com/JF7YlNu.png

Comment: I also checked if there length are different. However they show same size. http://i.imgur.com/D3pnXwv.png     .. Debug.log screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/MysJlEq.png

Answer (score 2):

The Split operation could result in an empty string at the end of your `linesinfile` array.

Try to check if `name` is valid, e.g. using `if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))`.

Comment: I tried adding a condition before Instantiation to check if linesinfile[0] == "F260001" and it came to false.. I am attaching screenshots.. http://i.imgur.com/9lk1klo.png            My debug.log after adding the condition: http://i.imgur.com/JJbTuWN.png

Comment: When I check using if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))   it comes to true and shows this error.. http://i.imgur.com/ghJs0Xw.png...    This was my code: http://i.imgur.com/eRVJoeE.png

Answer (score 1):

I also asked for help on the Unity answers forum and @corpsinheretoo  came to the rescue. The issue is with how I split the strings. I was using '\n' but some text editors add \r\n when press return.  So the string I thought looked like this: F26001\nF26002\nF26003 Really looks like this: F26001\r\nF26002\r\nF26003.

So i simply switched split to ';' and edited my code and text file like this and it worked. : https://i.stack.imgur.com/EY66g.png    and, text file: https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1kJz.png   ..

Comment: Here is a link to the original answer: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1310479/the-object-you-want-to-instantiate-is-null-1.html#answer-1311325