# The Object you want to instantiate is null. (Error Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've tried to fix this problem for many days, looked for every result in a web and didn't get any suitable answers to me...

With this problem I can run my game, but it shows up every time I shoot the bullet prefab.

This is a player shooting script, it shows up a problem when I try to **Instatiate(bulletRef);**

```
public GameObject bulletRef;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    bulletRef = Resources.Load("Bullet") as GameObject;   
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Z))
    {
        // By pressing the button we create an instance of a bullet
        Instantiate(bulletRef);
        bulletRef.transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x + .4f, transform.position.y + .2f, -1);
    }
}
```

I think that those codes look suspicious to me, maybe the roots of this problem are coming out from them

here is a script for bullet

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class BulletScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 20f;
    public int damage = 1;
    public Rigidbody2D rb;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb.velocity = -transform.up * speed;
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collider)
    {
        Destruction enemy = collider.GetComponent<Destruction>();
        if (enemy != null)
        {
            enemy.TakeDamage(damage);
        }

        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

This is a script for destroying the bullet. I don't personally think that there is an issue with this code, but it is for you to understand how my bullet dissapears

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Destruction : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int health = 1;

    public void TakeDamage(int damage)
    {
        health -= damage;

        if (health <= 0)
        {
            Die();
        }
    }

    void Die()
    {
        Destroy(this.gameObject);
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        ScoreManager.instance.AddPoint();
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than on other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The Object you want to instantiate is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42112395/the-object-you-want-to-instantiate-is-null)

Comment: Your code doesn’t keep a referb to the instantiated object. Not the most important but you are trying to move a prefab not the bullet. Assuming the bulletRef is a prefab.

Comment: @BugFinder but my bullet is a prefab, or should I just fire a non prefab bullet. But how will it work then?

Comment: Think of a prefab as a cookie cutter. You need to stamp your cookie then you move the cookie. That’s what should be moving around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in your `Update()` method of your first script

```cs
Instantiate(bulletRef);
bulletRef.transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x + .4f, transform.position.y + .2f, -1);
```

You are instantiating the gameobject `bulletRef` but not assigning it to any field. Also, you are changing the position of just a reference to the gameobject you just loaded from the resources. You didn't have a reference to the gameobject in the scene, you have a reference to the gameobject in your resources. To get a reference to the gameobject you just instantiated into your scene, assign the instantiated gameobject to a field. But the function `Instantiate` returns an `Object` hence we typecast it to `GameObject` as

```cs
GameObject bulletRefObject = Instantiate(bulletRef) as GameObject;
bulletRefObject.transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x + .4f, transform.position.y + .2f, -1);
```

Comment: When I Instantiate(bulletRef) it says that I cannot implicitly convert type 'UnityEngine.Object' to 'UnityEngine.GameObject'.

Comment: In the `Start()` method of your first snippet, change the code to this: `bulletRef = Resources.Load<GameObject>("Bullet");` @Makar, mention if this worked or not

Comment: I changed it, but it still shows me the same mistake, maybe the problem is in what I instantiate?
It's Underlining red Instantiate(bulletRef);

Comment: @Makar, I've edited my answer, take a look at it